# printf adding a \n in a format string

Tags: c, printf, fseek

I'm trying to build a version of the ar unix command in C. I'm working on the verbose output and I've got most of it covered. However, when I read through the file and put the file name in a format string a secret new line keeps popping up.

```
void verbose(char *archive){
    printf("\nI'm in -v!\n");

    int mode;
    size_t readNum;
    time_t mtime;
    struct tm * time_box;
    long long arch_size, file_size;
    long uID, gID;
    char header[60], file_name[16];
    char* tokens;
    FILE *fp = fopen(archive, "r");
    if (!fp)
        fail('f');

    //get file size
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    arch_size = ftell(fp);
    rewind(fp);

    //move over ARMAG
    if(fseek(fp, strlen(ARMAG), SEEK_SET) != 0)
        fail ('z');

    //loop over files
    while(ftell(fp) < arch_size -1){
        //reads header into
        readNum = fread(header, 1, sizeof(header), fp);
        if(readNum != sizeof(header))
            fail('r');

        tokens = strtok(header, " ");
        strcpy(file_name, tokens);
        mtime = (time_t)(atol(tokens = strtok(NULL, " ")));
        uID = atol(tokens = strtok(NULL, " "));
        gID = atol(tokens = strtok(NULL, " "));
        mode = atoi(tokens = strtok(NULL, " "));
        file_size = atoll(&header[48]);
        time_box = localtime(&mtime);

        printf("%d"
                "\t%ld"
                "/%ld"
                "\t\t%lld "
                "%s "
                "%s\n", mode, uID, gID, file_size, &asctime(time_box)[4], file_name);

        //move over file
        if(fseek(fp, file_size, SEEK_CUR) != 0)
            fail ('z');
    }
    fclose(fp);
}

void delete(){
    printf("\nI'm in -d!\n");
}
```

This code yields an ouput like this:

```
I'm in -v!
100644  502/20      28 Jan 27 16:23:59 2013
 b.txt
100644  502/20      17 Jan 27 16:24:06 2013
 c.txt
100644  502/20      28 Jan 27 16:24:15 2013
 d.txt
100644  502/20      17 Jan 27 16:24:06 2013
 c.txt
```

I can't figure out why the file name is on a new line. It's killing me. I thought that maybe I wasn't seeking properly, but if I move seek up by 1 byte it starts cutting off the name, so I don't think that's it.

Also, bonus, if anyone knows of a way to convert that octal to unix file permissions easily I would be stoked (ie, -rw-rw-rw)

Comment: That would have been great, I'm in Eclipse and the console area is much larger than the output. Plus, I've tested it down to just the file name and it adds a \n even if you just printf "%s", file_name;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `asctime` generates a C string that has `\n` before the `NUL` terminating character. Check out the reference [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/asctime/).

> The string is followed by a new-line character ('\n') and the terminating null-character.

Comment: Too true, I used strncpy to strip it out. Thanks for pointing that out!